# If $\operatorname{Ker}(T^k)=\operatorname{Ker}(T^{k+1})$ then in fact $\operatorname{Ker}(T^{k+c})=\operatorname{Ker}(T^k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, function-and-relation-composition

$\newcommand{\Ker}{\operatorname{Ker}}$Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and let $T : V → V$ be a linear map. Prove that if $\Ker(T^k)=\Ker(T^{k+1})$ then in fact $\Ker(T^{k+c})=\Ker(T^k)$ for all positive integers $c$.
I see that induction is likely to be the way forward - how can I prove that if if holds for some positive intger $c$, then it holds for $c+1$ also?

Comment: please edit the title

Comment: Instead of sharing that "my mind's gone blank", it would be more likely to elicit help from Readers if you shared what you do know about the problem.  If proof "for all positive integers $c$" is difficult, pick some easy positive integers $c$ to prove it for (and share your work).

Comment: Noted - I've changed the description. Thank you, will bear this in mind in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove by induction on $n \ge 0$ that $\ker T^{k+n}=\ker T^{k+n+1}$.

It's clear for $n = 0$ by hypothesis. Suppose that $\ker T^{k+n}=\ker T^{k+n+1}$. It's also clear that $\ker T^{k+n+1} \subseteq \ker T^{k+n+2}$. Now suppose that $T^{k+n+2}(x) = T^{k+n+1}(T(x))=0$. It means that $T(x) \in \ker T^{k+n+1}$ and by induction hypothesis that $T(x) \in \ker T^{k+n}$. Therefore $x \in \ker T^{k+n+1}$... and we're done.